# Bounding solid angle of tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry, simplex, finite-element-method

Let $K\subset \mathbb R^3$ be a non-degenerate tetrahedron. This tetrahedron has the property that the ratio between diameter and radius of insphere is bounded,
$$
d \le \kappa r\ \text{ for some } \ \kappa>0
$$
where $d$ is the diameter of $K$, whereas $r$ is the radius of the insphere.

Is it possible to derive a lower bound on the solid angels of the tetrahedron in terms of $\kappa$ only?

The purpose of such an estimate would be as follows: Let tetrahedrons $K_i$ be given, each satisfying the inequality above. Assume that they do not overlap and share one common vertex. Then the number of such tetrahedrons is bounded from above by a finite number.

---

I could easily prove the analogous result for triangles. The desired bound is Zlamal's minimum angle condition in this case.

---

Such an assumption as above is traditionally assumed in finite element methods. I could not find any proof of the above statement (bounding the number of tetrahedrons with one common vertex), which is in most references mentioned as fact.

Comment: The solid angle spanned by a tetrahedron at one of its vertices is larger than the solid angle spanned by the in-sphere at the same vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let  $x_0$ be the vertex of the angle in question, $x_i$ the midpoint of the insphere, and set $L:=|x_i-x_0|$. Then take a ball centered at $x_0$ with radius $\sqrt{L^2+r^2}$. The surface area $S$ of the projection of the tetrahedron onto this ball is $(r^2+L^2)\cdot \Theta$ with $\Theta$ being the solid angle. This area is larger than the area $S_i$ of the projection of the insphere onto the ball. The area $S_i$ is the surface of a spherical cap whose base circle is the circle with radius $r$ and center $x_i$. Hence, $S_i$ is larger than the area of this circle.
Since the insphere lies inside the tetrahedron, it holds
$\sqrt{L^2+r^2}\le d$, which implies
$$
\pi r^2 \le S_i \le S = (L^2+r^2)\cdot \Theta \le  d^2 \cdot \Theta.
$$
Now the left-hand side can be bounded from below by $\pi \kappa^{-2}d^2$,
which leads to the estimate
$$
\Theta\ge \pi \kappa^{-2}.
$$

Comment: Close but you need to justify $S_i \ge \pi r^2$ which isn't obvious (at least to me).  To complete the argument, let $L = |x-x_0|$, the half-angle $\theta$ of the cone spanned by the sphere at $x_0$ is equal to $\sin^{-1}\frac{r}{L}$. We have:
$$S_i = 2\pi L^2 \left(1 - \cos\theta\right) =  2\pi L^2\left(1 - \sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{L^2}}\right) = \frac{2\pi r^2}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{L^2}}}$$
and the RHS is clearly $\ge \pi r^2$.

Comment: if you do that, everything will be fine.

Comment: Hmm.. thinking about it, $\sqrt{L^2+r^2}$ is the distance between $x_0$ and a point on the in-sphere. Since the in-sphere is inside the tetrahedron, $\sqrt{r^2+L^2} \le d$ and you can get rid of the $\frac12$ in your inequality.